# CANNOT POST with brackets

Tags: node.js, post, adobe-brackets

I have a project, when I run with MAMP everything works fine. But when I run in brackets, it throws an error

CANNOT POST /b.html?xx=yy....

HTML:

```
<form id="emailForm" action="b.html" method="POST">
    <input id="emailModal" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required class="form-control input-lg" value=""></input>
</form>
```

JS:
Esta función convierte un objeto en una lista de parámetros.

```
  function objToParams(infoUserShow){
   var str = "";
   for (var key in infoUserShow) {
   if (str != "") {
    str += "&";
   }
       str += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(infoUserShow[key]);
   }
return str;
 }
```

This is the Object:

```
         var infoUserShow = {
          nickname : eventObj.user.nickname
          ,loginProvider : eventObj.user.loginProvider
          ,photoURL : eventObj.user.photoURL
          ,country : eventObj.user.country
          ,isLogged : false
        }

        console.log(objToParams(infoUserShow));
```

Here we make the submit to the 
            //Email exists validation
            var userMail = eventObj.user.email;
               if(!userMail) {

```
          //We customize the modal header for the customer
          document.getElementById('customMsg').innerHTML = "Hey " + infoUserShow.nickname + "!";

          $('#myModal').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
          });
          $('#myModal').modal('show');




        }else{
          //set user as logged
          infoUserShow.isLogged = true;

          //Add + 1 session to the cookie
          setAddCookie();

          //ADD parameters infoUserShow to the URL
          emailForm.action = "b.html" + objToParams(infoUserShow);

          emailForm.submit();
        }

        $('#Cancel').click(function() {
          $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });

        $('#Confirm').click(function() {
          var emailValidation = true; //data entered is correct

          if(emailValidation){
            //set user as logged
            infoUserShow.isLogged = true;

            //Add + 1 session to the cookie
            setAddCookie();

            //ADD parameters infoUserShow to the URL
            emailForm.action = "b.html?" + objToParams(infoUserShow);

            emailForm.submit();
          }

        });
```

Comment: Why `action="/b.html"` instead of `action="b.html"` ?

Comment: I had b.html but didn't work so I tried with the slash